# Can't delete google cloud project: no access

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to delete a Google Cloud project, I get this error:

> You are not allowed access: the project cannot be modified by the end user.

[image: Error: You are not allowed access: the project cannot be modified by the end user]

However, I can confirm I am logged in as the owner of the project, I checked permissions and this account is the only linked account for that cloud project (and is owner).

When I try to disable billing (as I suspect you can't delete a billing-enabled project), I get a similar error:

[image: Server Error: Whoops! Our bad. Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send feedback" link below. Copy the tracking number below, and include it with your feedback. Thanks! Tracking number: undefined. Send feedback.]

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Please use the *Send feedback* link in the UI to contact Google (particularly about the "Tracking Number: undefined" bit); there isn't enough information here for someone without access to your account and project.

Comment: Hello... i am also facing the same error when i am going to create client key for my ios app... is there any way to solve it from our side.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move to API&Auths->API 
disable all apis,
then try to delete again